# Alternatives for measuring internet Speed

Tags: performance, file, time, pagespeed, measurement

I've been using the `file download and time measuring strategy` for a long time, but when used in some very slow connections such as Cellular Data, of range <64 kbps, connection isn't much stable.

**Example**

If file is 100kb, almost 5 retries are made to download that particular file, and the speed measurement isn't accurate while taking the **time waited for each retry** into account.

So, Is there any other efficient method to measure internet speed accurately besides downloading a file, and measuring the time delay between request and completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, Is there any other efficient method to measure internet speed accurately ...

It depends what you are actually trying to measure:

- If you are trying to measure the theoretical speed (bit rate) of a particular link, you would need to consult the hardware / firmware documentation.  (For instance, my modem tells me the current upstream and downstream clock rate ...)
- If you are trying to measure *actual* transmission speed, that depends on many many things, and is liable to be highly variable ... depending on what you are doing, when you are doing it, etc.  The only meaningful measure of speed will be the actual speed measured *doing* whatever it is you are trying to do; e.g. downloading a file from a particular site.

> So, Is there any other efficient method to measure internet speed accurately besides downloading a file, and measuring the time delay between request and completion?

Basically, no.

You talk about the measured speed of downloading a 100Kb file.  I suspect that is not large enough for a TCP/IP connection to wind up to full speed.  Try measuring with a file of 1Mb, 10Mb and 100Mb, and I suspect you will get faster transmission rates.